Can I shrink a TeXLive installation?
I have just installed Tex Live 2022 final version on an older Windows computer and it takes about 6 GB of disk space.  Did I miss an option for a minimal install somewhere?  Can I shrink this installation after the fact?
PS. I used the command:
install-tl-windows -repository ftp://tug.org/tex/texlive/historic/2022/tlnet-final
as suggested on:
https://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html

welcome! re. first question: if you use upstream's installer, during installation you can customise what is installed based on various 'schemes' and other options e.g. whether to install documentation etc. schemes vary in coverage i.e. you can choose to install everything or a minimal scheme or something in between. however, I'm not sure how this works or if you get the same options with the gui installer as I've never used it. I don't know about the second question.

You might also be interested in this question:  Why can't TeX Live's size be reduced?. There are things you can do, but you can't reduce TeX Live's size by that much. You may also want to consider other distributions like MikTeX, which installs packages on the fly rather than including things you might not need.

@gz839918 that is simply not true. it is easy to install a much reduced texlive. the advantage of miktex is that you can install a reduce distribution and not be (very) inconvenienced by missing packages because they can be installed on-the-fly. with texlive, you can install very little, but every time you need something not included you have to manually invoke tlmgr to install it (or download it and drop it into your working directory or whatever). but just installing less of it is easy: just choose the smallest 'scheme', no doc tree etc.

BTW: Why have you installed TeX Live 2022 instead of the current version?

@cfr There is texliveonfly (also available in TeX Live) to automatically install missing packages using TeX Live.

@cabohah thanks. I'd forgotten about texliveonfly. however, it says it is designed to work on linux and should work on os x, so is it an option on windows? it's also rather old and would require python, which is not a significant prerequisite on linux, but I think might be on windows?

Thanks for all the quick reactions.  The computer is older, hence 2022.  Main motivation is that some python programs I'm working on ask for pdflatex.  Otherwise I mostly work on Overleaf.  I wouldn't mind manually adding missing packages.

@cfr I indeed don't know, if it works on windows. I've not used windows for several years.


Did I miss an option for a minimal install somewhere?

Yes, there is an Advanced button of the installer.  There I could have selected a small scheme such as 'scheme-minimal'.

Can I shrink this installation after the fact?

Yes, using tlshell.  Selected a few of the bigger schemes in the list and click on remove.  This actually doesn't shrink the installation right away because the uninstalled packages are moved to a backup folder: `texlive\2022\tlpkg\backups.  So to really shrink the installation, delete the backup files.
